# Linux kernel version and GCC version match

Tags: kernel, gcc

Is there a recommended GCC version for compiling the Linux kernel?

I find Linux kernel's header "compiler-GCC ". Does it include information about the kernel's recommended GCC  version? That is, can I find information about compiling in the Linux kernel source code?

Comment: Are you asking what GCC versions are recommended (or supported) for *compiling* particular kernel versions? I recommend you [edit] this with more details about what you're trying to find out. Are you looking for the significance of `include/linux/compiler-gcc.h` in the kernel headers? Is this related to the version of GCC that was used to build a the currently running kernel binary, as shown in the output of `cat /proc/version`? The Linux kernel and GCC are separate projects--they're not released together. Can you [edit] in an explanation of what you mean by "matching kernel and gcc version"?

Comment: I mean when compiling kernel, is there recommended compiler version?

Comment: Or kernel compile well with any gcc version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to build the Linux kernel with a pretty old version of GCC, probably back as far as GCC 3.2. [The top-level README file in Linux 4.9.4](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/README?id=refs/tags/v4.9.4) mentions:

```
 - Make sure you have at least gcc 3.2 available.
   For more information, refer to Documentation/Changes.
```

And [Documentation/Changes](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/Changes?id=refs/tags/v4.9.4) gives a list of required versions of GCC (listed as "GNU C") and the other build dependencies for Linux, as well as *how* to check what version of each you currently have installed:

```
====================== ===============  ========================================
        Program        Minimal version       Command to check the version
====================== ===============  ========================================
GNU C                  3.2              gcc --version
GNU make               3.80             make --version
binutils               2.12             ld -v
util-linux             2.10o            fdformat --version
module-init-tools      0.9.10           depmod -V
e2fsprogs              1.41.4           e2fsck -V
jfsutils               1.1.3            fsck.jfs -V
reiserfsprogs          3.6.3            reiserfsck -V
xfsprogs               2.6.0            xfs_db -V
squashfs-tools         4.0              mksquashfs -version
btrfs-progs            0.18             btrfsck
pcmciautils            004              pccardctl -V
quota-tools            3.09             quota -V
PPP                    2.4.0            pppd --version
isdn4k-utils           3.1pre1          isdnctrl 2>&1|grep version
nfs-utils              1.0.5            showmount --version
procps                 3.2.0            ps --version
oprofile               0.9              oprofiled --version
udev                   081              udevd --version
grub                   0.93             grub --version || grub-install --version
mcelog                 0.6              mcelog --version
iptables               1.4.2            iptables -V
openssl & libcrypto    1.0.0            openssl version
bc                     1.06.95          bc --version
Sphinx\ [#f1]_         1.2              sphinx-build --version
====================== ===============  ========================================

.. [#f1] Sphinx is needed only to build the Kernel documentation
```

It's a good idea to check the `Documentation/Changes` file in the kernel source you're actually planning on compiling.

With all that said, it's probably a good idea to use a relatively recent version of GCC, since newer versions have better optimizers and thus can often produce faster code, and since newer versions have more readable diagnostics so it may be easier to figure out what went wrong of your build fails.

In general, I recommend using the version of GCC that is officially packaged for your system. In Ubuntu, the version of GCC that is installed as a dependency of the `build-essential` metapackage should always be sufficient, at least for building kernels that aren't *far* newer than the kernel officially packaged for your system.

Comment: Well, GCC 7.5 could not build bootable kernel 3.0.101 for ARM32 because of some optimizations. The same time GCC 4.8.3 did it great. Check-mate)

Comment: what tool to check system software version automatically？

Comment: Note that the location of this documentation has move to: `https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/process/changes.rst?id=refs/tags/vX.X.X`. Simply change `X.X.X` to the desired version.